# Bootstrap 3 collapsed menu doesn't close on click in Angular4

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have been facing with the above problem in Angular. For mobile device the menu should collapse once it get select any one of them but it doesn't close on click.

Please help me out to get rid from this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. [Please remember to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when creating questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your (click) method, whatever is it called to toggle the variable the toggle is tied to.

```
menuOpenVariable: any = false;

clickedMenuItem(){
menuOpenVariable = false; // re-close the menu on yor click method.
  // do menu things
}
```

And this should all be linked to your HTML file where the menu 'lives'.

```
<menu menuOpenVariable> 
  <menu-item (click)="clickedMenuItem()">item 1</menu-item>
</menu>
```